# Pass a parameter to Custom mapping function

Tags: java, mapstruct

Using `MapStruct`, and would like to pass a constant/parameter to a Custom Mapper

I have destination that has a field of type `Map<String, Restriction> restrictions`.  The source may have 2-3 String fields that need to be mapped to a single Restriction in the map.  The key to the Map is just a constant.  Using Map-struct Mapping annotation, I would like to pass this key into the custom mapper so that I can either create the initial value in the Map or retrieve an existing value in the Map.

```
   @Mappings({

          @Mapping(source="source.someField", target="restrictions", constant="someKey"),

          @Mapping(source="source.startDate", target="restrictions", constant="someKey"),

          @Mapping(source="source.EndDate", target="restrictions", constant="someKey")

   })

   public abstract void restrictToClassA(SomeDataEntity source, @MappingTarget ClassA destination);
```

Answer (score 2):

Constant is an alternative to target. You cannot specify both in the same @Mapping annotation. But, from your story I gather that you have control over your 'ClassA' destination. So, you could group your mappings into quadruplets. So:

```java
Public Quadrupel{

   String prop1;
   String prop2;
   String prop3;
    //Getters/setters

}

ClassA{

   Quadrupel key1;
   Quadrupel key2;
    //Etc
    //Getters/setters

}
```

Into ClassA. Properties would then be along the lines of your key name. Your custom mapper could pick those up and map them in your target map. Although, the key would then a bit dubious as well since the property would indicate the same